# Offworld trading company placing HQ on top of resource?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

Are you supposed to do it or not? What are the benefits / downsides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing your HQ on top of resource tiles has the following effects:

- You immediately receive a quantity of these resources.
  *Quantity appears to be currently 20 for each low tile covered, 30 for mediums, 40 for highs.

  Note that Robotic HQs receive twice as much as the other HQs.*
- Those tiles not available to use for the rest of the match.

The latter *could* be a downside if you didn't choose your location carefully, otherwise I would say that **you almost always want to place your HQ on some resource tiles to get yourself some free starting resources**.

Unless you completely cover a section of a resource, doing this will also allow you to then place extraction buildings for that resource adjacent to your HQ, avoiding transportation fuel and time costs.

Finally, there's also a possibly that you can block access to resources your opponents might need or want (for example, covering up good water sources if you're going in as Robotic might be a worthwhile tactic if water is sparse).